# I'm trying to make a basic calculator in python. I'm including an index of functions

Tags: python, math

I should also note I'm using python 3.6.

```
funcs = [add,sub,mult,div,power]
```

Above is the function index.

```
chosenfunc = chooseFunc()
for i in funcs:
    if i == chosenfunc:
        i(x,y)
```

This above is how I'm trying to access it.
So that it basically runs `add()`.
And if it's relevant, my add function is written as:

```
def add(x,y):
    print(f"Result of {x} + {y}: {(float(x)) + (float(y))}")
```

How do I get it to run my function? It doesn't do anything currently.

```
import fractions

funcs = [add,sub,mult,div,power]

def chooseFunc():
    return input("Choose a function from between Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, power: ")

def numtofloat(num):
    return float(num)

def add(x,y):
    print(f"Result of {x} + {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) + (numtofloat(y))}")
def sub(x,y):
    print(f"Result of {x} - {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) - (numtofloat(y))}")
def mult(x,y):
    print(f"Result of {x} * {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) * (numtofloat(y))}")
def div(x,y):
    print(f"Result of {x} / {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) / (numtofloat(y))}")
def power(x,y):
    print(f"Result of {x} ^ {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) ^ (numtofloat(y))}")

chosenfunc = chooseFunc()
for i in funcs:
    if i == chosenfunc:
        i()
```

Edited to add full code.

Comment: I just updated it. I realized I didn't add the actual question

Comment: You're going to need to show a [mcve]. I ran your code after filling in some of the gaps, and it works fine (for `add`). What is `chooseFunc`?

Comment: why not call `chosenfunc(x,y)` directly?

Comment: `chooseFunc` just runs `input` and asks for a function from a list. i.e. `Add`
the error I get is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Code/Calculator/Calc.py", line 4, in <module>
    funcs = [add,sub,mult,div,power]
NameError: name 'add' is not defined`
And I'm not sure why it does that. I'll add my full code in the main post

Comment: Chris, I plan on adding a lot of functions to this over time. And I feel an individual line for each function would be more clutter than I'd like. Probably redundant but I'd rather do it this way if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do so...

```py
def add(x, y):
    print(x + y)


funcs = [add, ]


def chooseFunc():
    # take input here for function by index or something
    return 0


chosenfunc = chooseFunc()

for i in range(len(funcs)):
    if i == chosenfunc:
        funcs[i](2, 3)
```

EDIT: Question got changed :)

```py
import fractions


def numtofloat(num):
    return float(num)


def add(x, y):
    print(f"Result of {x} + {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) + (numtofloat(y))}")


def sub(x, y):
    print(f"Result of {x} - {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) - (numtofloat(y))}")


def mult(x, y):
    print(f"Result of {x} * {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) * (numtofloat(y))}")


def div(x, y):
    print(f"Result of {x} / {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) / (numtofloat(y))}")


def power(x, y):
    print(f"Result of {x} ^ {y}: {(numtofloat(x)) ^ (numtofloat(y))}")


funcs = {"add": add, "sub": sub, "mult": mult, "div": div, "power": power}


def chooseFunc():
    return input("Choose a function from between add, sub, mult, div, power: ")


x, y = 2, 3

chosenfunc = chooseFunc()
for i in funcs.keys():
    if i == chosenfunc:
        funcs[i](x, y)
```

Added x, y to pass to function using dict to keep function mapping, also moved function def before mapping

Comment: Nope there will be type error as you'll have to cast string input from user to function or variable

Comment: Yeah, I was originally getting a type error. I'll try what you just added and see if that works. Thanks so far!

Comment: Yup it's working np, you'll get an error in power however because ** operator is used to calculate power. Also no need to import fractions :)